# Cross browser compatibility issue: displaying images

Tags: html, image, cross-browser

I display images in an application like this:

```
<img src="\\999.99.99.999\Project\Images\logo.png" alt="logo" \>
```

The images are in a remote machine, in a specific folder, and are correctly displayed in my webpages if I'm using Internet Explorer. However, the images don't display at all in any other browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, ...).

I've searched the web and I found many references to the opposite problem (images that are displayed in many browsers but not on IE) but none to this particular problem.

Can someone help?

**EDIT**

I've tried different approaches but the result is even less satisfactory: the images aren't displayed in any browser, here are some examples:

```
<img src="//999.99.99.999/Project/Images/logo.png" alt="logo" \>
<img src="http://999.99.99.999/Project/Images/logo.png" alt="logo" \>
<img src="file://999.99.99.999/Project/Images/logo.png" alt="logo" \>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to display images (or other media content) you should using apropriate URI scheme

```
protocol://server_addr/path/file.ext
```

something like

```
http://127.0.0.1/images/picture.jpg
```

In your example it seems that you trying to download image through CIFS (pay attention at backward slashes and 2 backward slashes at start) it most likely MS's network protocol, so internet explorer can work with it, but firefox and opera can't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I try your suggestion the images don't display in any browser, not even IE

Comment: You need that remote machine has installed and started web-server like IIS or Apache.

Comment: Can you explain better please?

Comment: Installing and configurating web server is complicated task, if you don't have a clue what it is. Maybe you should just copy that image file from remote server and paste it in same folder where your html file is? And then simple use it like `<img src="filename.jpg" alt="" />`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask you to explain how to install and configure a web server, I wanted you to explain why do you say that is needed in order to display images in a browser that's not IE. Is that configuration what makes the file accessible via the http protocol? On a side note, copying the image to the local machine isn't a solution since the web application will be accessed from many machines and it gets many elements from a single remote one (the server).

Comment: In your first example you try to display an image in browser through the CIFS protocol `\\255.255.255.255\path\file.ext`. Internet Explorer can work with this protocol, firefox, chrome, opera cannot. For work your page in any browser you should use HTTP protocol, since it supported by all browser include IE.

Comment: That would make sense but, if I type `\\999.99.99.999\Project\Images\logo.png` in the address bar, the image shows, on **every** browser. How can that be then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62524/discussion-between-mark-zucchini-and-chiapa).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a [protocol-relative url](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) but you have the slashes the wrong way round (should be `//` not `\\`) - in fact all the slashes in the url should be forward slashes

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I try your suggestion the images don't display in any browser, not even IE

Comment: sounds like your images are not available via http - are you sure that you are running a correctly configured web server hosting the images? can you view the images in a browser by putting the url value from your html into the address bar?

Comment: No, they show if I type `\\999.99.99.999\Project\Images\logo.png` or `file://999.99.99.999/Project/Images/logo.png`: if I type `http://999.99.99.999/Project/Images/logo.png` they don't show